# How to limit number of tty in systemd

Tags: systemd, tty

If I run `systemctl` I get a lot of ttys (see above). Is there any way to limit this number and so save some memory because obviously I will not need this bunch of tty never.

```
sys-devices-virtual-tty-ttya0.device                    loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/tty/ttya0
[...]
sys-devices-virtual-tty-ttyzf.device                    loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/virtual/tty/ttyzf
```

Comment: It's `logind.conf` and `locate logind.conf` finds it at `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

Comment: @MarkStosberg it's not a duplicate, that's referring to launching gettys on the TTY devices, this is about the TTY devices themselves

Comment: @ShaunBouckaert exactly! After consulting that other question, I also noticed almost immediately, that this is not the same issue. I am currently investigating this in order to speed up the boot. A whopping 256 of these "virtual tty" devices get their own unit courtesy of the respective entries in `/sys/devices`. In my case Ubuntu 18.04 on a Cubietruck (Armbian with 4.19 kernel). A similar Ubuntu 18.04 system on x86 doesn't show _any_ of these devices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is related to the following two settings in the kernel configuration ([source](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?t=15848)):

```
$ zgrep CONFIG_LEGACY_PTY /proc/config.gz 
CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS=y
CONFIG_LEGACY_PTY_COUNT=256
```

I was observing this behavior on a Cubietruck, where apparently this number of legacy PTYs is configured. Thanks to `systemd-analyze plot` I had noticed this as being a major factor in delaying the boot on my device.

Turns out there is a [kernel command line option](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html) which can restrict the number *dynamically*:

```
pty.legacy_count=N
```

(where `N` is the number you want set)

For me this meant to add a line like this:

```
extraargs=pty.legacy_count=6
```

... to `/boot/armbianEnv.txt` (further options can be added, separated by spaces; just *do not* enclose the right side of the first `=` in double quotes!).

After that I ran:

```
mkimage -C none -A arm -T script -d /boot/boot.cmd /boot/boot.scr
```

... because I was unsure whether the `armbianEnv.txt` gets "compiled" into the script image. I don't think so, but I didn't want to waste any time.

Anyway, a quick look with:

```
systemctl |grep virtual-tty|wc -l
```

... confirms that there are now just 6 of those legacy PTYs.

Depending on your particular device the whole setting could also be in the form of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` (or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`) in `/etc/default/grub` or where ever GRUB stores its configuration for your distro (don't forget to `update-grub` after your changes).